# Get ObjectId (Parse) from TableView row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, tableview

I have a Parse Class named "Restaurantes" (Restaurants in english) and currently i can list all the restaurants in a CustomTableView.

Now my goal is when i choose a restaurant from the list, it shows the "menus" of each restaurant. For this I have to pass the Restaurant ObjectId using prepareForSegue and in the new ViewController have a query to list all the "menus" for that restaurant ObjectId.

How can I get the ObjectId of the restaurant that user clicked? (swift)

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import AVFoundation

class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var queryArray: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurantes")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Restaurantes.")
            if let _objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                self.queryArray = _objects
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return queryArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ListaTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListaTableViewCell

    //Insert text in tableview
    let restaurante = queryArray[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
    cell.textCell.text = restaurante.objectForKey("nome") as! String



    //Insert images in tableview
    if let userPicture = restaurante.objectForKey("imagem1") as? PFFile {

        userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                cell.imageBg.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)                }
        }
    }


    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "cell" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MenuPageViewController {
            if let blogIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {




            }
        }
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Don't pass the `objectId`, pass the whole object. And the object should have a relationship to the menus that you can explicitly query...

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "cell" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MenuPageViewController {
            if let blogIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                // Get the object restaurant object from your array
                 let restaurante = queryArray[blogIndex] as! PFObject
                // set object id to the property in destination 
                 destination.resturantId = restaurant.objectId
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Imagine that between `viewDidLoad` and user click on a row, someone add a new restaurant. The `prepareForSegue` query will return a wrong restaurant. =/

Comment: Best practice says that if you are changing your dataSource then you should also apply those changes to tableView and vice versa... so if you are adding rows in array then you should also insert those rows into the table...

Comment: Thats not a best practice for all apps. In my case, a user can add a restaurant and other user can list the restaurants available and can pull down to refresh.

Comment: When you are populating a tableView and also setting dataSource in your case queryArray, then your dataSource and tableView should match other wise you will create some anomalies. Because User will see option one and will select that but ur underlaying dataStructure will not be same which  will not be right behavior.